# When doing fragment caching, should we cache active record queries as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

If one is fragment caching a part of the page that has content loaded from models in the controller. Should these queries also be cached?

Does this mean there will be two types of caching: fragment and active support caching for two different types of data?

For example. In the view I could have:

```
<% cache 'videos_and_photos', :expires_in => 24.hours do %>
  <div id="videos">
    <% @videos.each do |video| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div id="photos">
    <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
       ...
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and in the controller:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('videos', :expires_in => 24.hours) do
  @videos = Video.where(...)
end

Rails.cache.fetch('photos', :expires_in => 24.hours) do
  @photos = Photo.where(...)
end
```

My only grip with this is, if one cache expires first, then the data will display inconsistently. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one should not use business logic or queries in views, but in this case it is possible to make an exception. Just define a special method for your query, for instance `Video.your_method`, and use it in the view. This seems to be the cleanest way to do it:

```
<% cache 'videos_and_photos', :expires_in => 24.hours do %>   
  <div id="videos">
    <% Video.your_method.each do |video| %>
      ...
    <% end %>   
  </div>
```

Otherwise you are caching data which belongs together in two different places, which may lead to unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a gem to avoid having to query the database if a cache exists.

https://github.com/rovermicrover/FlagpoleSitta

It stores all the database calls in Procs, and then only calls them if the cache doesn't exist. It then invalidates all related caches when an object gets updated. I got the idea from the following stackoverflow post.

[Best way to combine fragment and object caching for memcached and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034910/best-way-to-combine-fragment-and-object-caching-for-memcached-and-rails/1035832#1035832)

While my gem might be over kill, and I still considered it in beta, the over all strat from the above stack overflow post should help.